# Help me find my friend!

Tags: lateral-thinking, computer-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

I need your help! My friend has gone missing and I have no clue where he could be! However, he did manage to get a message out to me:

> Kidnapped. Send help. I am here:
>
> ***port town*. $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{x}{500334.5}}\right\rfloor$, add $^{\circ}\ '$**
>
> - Rick
>
> P.S. Remember my favourite three things!

Obviously, he hid the location, and that is where I need your help. To aid you, I vaguely remember him mentioning his favourite three things as **fonts**, the number **18** and the **OEIS**.

To send for help, I need both the **city** and **country** that he is currently in. Thanks for your help!

---

**Hint**:

> Only the **bold** bits and the formula are relevant to the puzzle.

---

**Extra notes (hints):**

It turns out Rick was able to send another note:

> Try writing the special part of the original message in a different font.
>
>  - Rick

And another:

> When you find the two hidden numbers $x$ and $y$...
>  `OEIS[x][y]`
>
>  - Rick

Comment: It's a bit unclear, is the formula relevant or not?

Comment: @Areeb it IS relevant to the question. I'll try to make it a bit more obvious. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is the apostrophe relevant, as it seems to be bolded?

Comment: @mestackoverflow quite sure it is relevant. The degree and apostrophe look like they denote map coordinates.

Comment: @GamrCorps is add referring to a function?

Comment: @Areeb not a mathematical function, but the function of combining two things together.

Comment: If anyone wants here's Oeis A000018: https://oeis.org/A000018

Comment: That's three pretty weird favorite things.

Comment: @DanRussell Not where we come from: [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can get some numbers from 'port town' if you change the font to Wingdings 2.

Comment: @WesleySitu I don't have that here, can you paste the result?

Comment: @Jasen Sorry for the late reply, but here you go! http://imgur.com/V65VCSP

Comment: 7,6,9,-0,-0,6,-3,5  (because the glyphs are described as "negative") but OEIS has nothing,

Answer (score 1):

I think he is in:

> Grado, Italy

***port town***:

> It's italicized so that represents Italy, and it's a port town

formula and add:

> I have no idea how that factors in

degree symbol:

> Degree in Italian is "Grado"; hence Grado, Italy

**'**:

> again no idea

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. All of the pieces play a role in the solution.

Comment: @GamrCorps did i atleast get Italy correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Welp so much for that lead

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but is your friend is in

> France in Le Havre?

I vaguely remember him mentioning his favourite three things as fonts, the number 18 and the OEIS.

> Searching for word OEIS, give me `On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences` 
>  When I cross reference name of sequences with fonts, I found weird font and sequence.
>  I used 18th number from  weird sequence (13510) in your formula, and that give me number 0.1643226573
>  
>  and I draw lines on map with latitude and longtitude 0.1643226573.
>  Le Havre was biggest port town on my line, and hence my pick.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Not in France.